# Graphs with different types of nodes

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have the following pandas dateframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id_emp':[13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113],
'name_emp': [
    'JL Consultores',
    'GRAAL OURINHOS',
    'SOJA COMERCIO DE DERIVADOS DE PETROLEO LTDA'
],
'name_dep': [
    'DIONILSO MATEUS MARCON',
    'JOSE AUGUSTO ROSA',
    'LUCIO ANTONIO MOSQUINI'
],
'donnated_value': [ 750.00, 5000.00, 27350.00],
'donnated_amount': [1,1,1],
'reimbursed_value':[36000.00,410.55, 241.22],
'amount_reimbursed': [1,2,1],
'roi':[4800.00, 8.21,0.88]
})
```

From this Dataframe, I plot a graph with the code below:

```
# Create graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Add id_emp nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'])
# Set 'name_emp' attribute for 'name_emp' column values
for node in G.nodes:
   G.nodes[node]['name_emp'] = df.loc[df['id_emp'] == node]['name_emp'].values[0]
# Add name_dep nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'])
# Create the new column with transformed 'roi' values
df['roi_new'] = df['roi'].apply(
lambda x: 1 if x < 100 else 2 if 100 <= x < 1000 else 3)
# Add weighted edges
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'roi_new']].values)
```

I need to improve the visualization of this graph. For this I would like the nodes from df ['id_emp' and df ['name_dep'] to be in different color and format. In addition, ideally each type of node would be on separate sides. Example: The df nodes ['id_emp] would stay at the top of the figure, while the others would stay at the bottom. Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a `'type_'` attribute for all nodes that represents is it `id_emp` or `name_dep` (replace the existing lines of code, don't add them!):

```
# Add id_emp nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], type_='id_emp')
...
# Add name_dep nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], type_='name_dep')
```

2. Set `colors` list for further node coloring:

```
colors = ['#0000FF' if G.nodes[n]['type_'] == 'id_emp' else '#FF0000' for n in G.nodes]
```

3. Set `pos` dict for further node positioning (needs `random` module and returns not an ideal results; if you want to draw nodes/edges better, you need a more complicated graph analysis):

```
pos = {
    n: (
        random.random(),
        0 if G.nodes[n]['type_'] == 'id_emp' else 1
    )
    for n in G.nodes
}
```

4. Draw the graph:

```
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=pos,
    node_color=colors,
    with_labels=True
)
```

[image]

You can read more about `networkx` graph drawing [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx).

Comment: How do I draw the edges with thickness according to the weight? Also, is it possible to put just one caption for the two distinct types of nodes?

Comment: 1. `linewidths` attribute (similar to `colors`). 2. No, it is not possible without questinable bad code.

Comment: I'm trying this, without sucessfull:   linewidth = [1.0 if df_ciclos_diretos['peso'][i] == 1.0 else 5.0 if df_ciclos_diretos['peso'][i] == 5.0
            else 10.0 if df_ciclos_diretos['peso'][i] == 10.0 for i in df_ciclos_diretos['peso']]